# React Native 2 navigation options

Tags: react-native

I have got a problem with 'react-navigation' in RN. 
In my app i have got DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator.
I am in third view in StackNavigator. I trying to go to first view and change tab in drawer Navigator. 
Code in my third view when i trying make this event

```
                           let navigateAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                              index: 0,
                              routeName:'Home',
                              actions: [
                                  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })
                              ]
                          });
                          let navigateActionDrawer = NavigationActions.navigate({
                             index: 0,
                             routeName:'Reservations',
                             actions: [
                                 NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Reservations'}),
                             ]
                         });
                              object.state.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
                              object.state.navigation.dispatch(navigateActionDrawer)
```

What I need to do to make correct this action ?

Comment: can you show your navigators. and mention the screen from which your trying to navigate and the destination screen.

Comment: const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Find: {
      screen: Find,
    },
    Reservations: {
      screen: Reservations,
    },

Comment: const Find = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: MyHomeScreen,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details,
  },

Answer (score 0):

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        key: null,
                        actions: [ 
                            NavigationActions.navigate({
                            routeName:'Reservations',
                           }),
                        ],
                      });
```

Try this. you have to reset to the parent and pass action that you want to navigate if nested.

Comment: There is no route defined for key Reservations. 
Must be one of: "Home","Details","Order"

Comment: @PiotrHołub updated the answer please check now. there was a small mistake before

Comment: No its not working, i will fix it:
I made "NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home', params: { fromReservation: true } })" and when i came back to Home app recoginzing it and create new Navigate

Comment: @PiotrHołub I thought your screens were nested. looks like the Reservation is in root itself. Just resetting to root and mentioning action to Reservations should work. Passing params and redirecting is not prefered